# How do I look up a SiteMapNode by its URL (or other key)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, sitemap, sitemapnode

I think the C# ASP.NET SiteMap uses URL as a dictionary key internally since it has to lookup by URL all the time, and forces them to be unique.  I want to use that lookup table, but I can't seem to find access to it.

What is the most efficient way to get a specific SiteMapNode by URL?  Is there access to it?

My use case is that I want to make a navigation bar populated from the sitemap, starting with the node that's two deep from the root, in my current node's parent chain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it.  It's the SiteMapProvider class that provides the method, not SiteMap or SiteMapNode, where I was looking.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.findsitemapnodefromkey.aspx.

I was able to use it like this:

```
var node = SiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey(key);
```

Comment: Just notice that to search by Url you have to use: FindSiteMapNode